# Interval of existence of a certain first-order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Without solving the following initial value problem, determine the interval in which the solution is certain to exist: $$\dfrac{dy}{dx}+(\tan x)y=\sin x, \ \ \ y \left (\frac{\pi}{4} \right )=0.$$

Please help me also solve (if you can) under what conditions the solution of the first-order ordinary differential equation exists?

This question is different is differenr from the previously asked queston in a way that it has two parts furthermore, the equation given is completely different from the previously asked question.

It is sad that none of the repliers have answered the question yet whereas they have accepted that they know answers. I am extremely disappointed with this forum which was suggested to me by my friend. Leaving it right now. Good Bye.

Comment: Have you studied any existence theorems for first order ODEs?

Comment: no ihvnt, can u answer this?

Comment: Yes, of course. However, if you have not studied existence theorems for first order ODEs and tried to apply them to this problem yourself first, people here will probably not help you. People will try to give you hints and guide you in the right direction. You should take their advice graciously and not repeatedly ask for the correct answer to your problem.

Comment: i mean i have read those theorems but confused with this eqn

Comment: And how did you apply a theorem to this problem? Where exactly is your confusion in applying the theorem?

Comment: i multtiplied the eqn with sec x and it became ddx[secxy(x)]=secxy′(x)+secxtanxy(x).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/898048/differential-equation-sin-theta-fracdrd-thetar-cos-theta-tan-theta

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Multiply the entire equation by $\sec{x}$ and note that

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\sec{x}\,y(x)\right]=\sec{x}\,y^\prime{(x)}+\sec{x}\tan{x}\,y(x).$$

Comment: just need intervals :(

Comment: please solve David H