# Solving using integrating factor

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> Q) Solve $y' = 2x + y$ using the integrating factor.

Can anyone guide me with steps here?
        Help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: For example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/898048/differential-equation-sin-theta-fracdrd-thetar-cos-theta-tan-theta

Answer (score 2):

Integrating factor for $$\frac{dy}{dx}+p(x)y=q(x)$$ is simply given by $$I(x)=e^{\int p(x)dx}.$$ For your case choose proper $p(x)$ and $q(x).$

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your equation as $y' - y = 2x$, then the integrating factor is $\mu(x) = \exp\{\int -1\, dx\} = e^{-x}$. Multiplying the equation by the integrating factor, you get
$$\left[ e^{-x}y \right]' = e^{-x}y' - e^{-x}y = 2xe^{-x}.$$

You integrate to get
$$e^{-x}y = -2xe^{-x} - 2e^{-x} + C,$$
and multiplying both sides by $e^x$ gives
$$y = -2x - 2 + Ce^x.$$

Answer (score 0):

In general;

For the D.E.

$$y'+b(x)y=g(x)$$ the integrating factor is $$\mu(x)=e^{\int b(x) \; \mathrm{d}x}$$